# Errors when trying to delete head, or node in the middle, of a linked list

Tags: c++, c++14

I know where is wrong but I don't know how to change it. Help, please! The only working is this `(CurrentNode->next == NULL)` if else case  the other doesn't. What can I do?

```
void Restaurant::deletereservation()
{
    string name;        
    cout << "Enter name of customer that you want to delete: " << endl
    << "Name: ";
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    getline(cin, name);
    ReservationNode *nodeIn = head;           
    ReservationNode *CurrentNode = head->next;  
    while ((CurrentNode != NULL) && (CurrentNode->Name != name))
    {
        nodeIn = CurrentNode;
        CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;
    }
    if (CurrentNode->Name != name){
        cout << "Error!!!" << name << " is not found.Cant be deleted if there is no such person." << endl;
    }
    else{
        if (nodeIn == head){
            CurrentNode = head->next;
            CurrentNode = head;
            delete nodeIn;          

        }
        else if(CurrentNode->next == NULL){
            nodeIn ->next = NULL;
            delete CurrentNode;             
        }
        else{
            nodeIn -> next = CurrentNode->next;
            delete CurrentNode; 
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please put a minimum compilable code to allow debbugging and executing? With only a method, it is difficult to reproduce your problem

Comment: What you can do is, first step: take a [tour] of stackoverflow.com, then: read the [help], and learn [ask] questions here that can be answered. It will not be possible for anyone to help you because your questions fails to meet all requirements for a [mre]. C++ functions don't exist in a vacuum. Whether they work, or not, depends on all other functions in your program. Which you have not shown. Nobody can help you with code that's not even shown. This doesn't mean that you should post your entire program, but only a [mre].

Comment: Not very sure why you declared `nodeIn`. You use `nodeIn = CurrentNode;` point to the same data  with `CurrentNode` and you then `delete nodeIn; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is correct because so much of the actual code is missing.

```
void Restaurant::deletereservation()
{
    string name;        
    cout << "Enter name of customer that you want to delete: " << endl
    << "Name: ";
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    getline(cin, name);
    ReservationNode *nodeIn = nullptr;           
    ReservationNode *CurrentNode = head;  
    while ((CurrentNode != NULL) && (CurrentNode->Name != name))
    {
        nodeIn = CurrentNode;
        CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;
    }
    if (CurrentNode == nullptr || CurrentNode->Name != name){
        cout << "Error!!!" << name << " is not found.Cant be deleted if there is no such person." << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (CurrentNode == head) {
        head = CurrentNode->next; // Cut off list head (CurrentNode)  
    }
    else{
        nodeIn->next = CurrentNode->next; // Make the list "skip" CurrentNode
    }
    delete CurrentNode;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1: This

```
ReservationNode *nodeIn = head;           
ReservationNode *CurrentNode = head->next;
```

is undefined if the list is empty.
You can just return if it is.

2: If the node isn't found in this loop:

```
while ((CurrentNode != NULL) && (CurrentNode->Name != name))
```

`CurrentNode` will be null after the loop, but you go right ahead and unconditionally dereference it:

```
if (CurrentNode->Name != name){
```

That test should be

```
if (CurrentNode == NULL){
```

3: This

```
if (nodeIn == head){
    CurrentNode = head->next;
    CurrentNode = head;
    delete nodeIn;          
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (nodeIn == head){
    CurrentNode = head;
    delete head;
}
```

and then `head` points to a node you just destroyed.

It should be

```
if (nodeIn == head){
    CurrentNode = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete CurrentNode;
}
```

Side note: things become much simpler if you separate user interaction from data manipulation.

Make a member that takes a name and deletes the corresponding entry.
Leave retrieving that name to the main program.